# Intercept all network communication that happens within the WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, okhttp, intercept

I'd like to be able to stand between the WebView and the Server and observe and modify any data that goes in or out. This needs to happen **within the host application**.

I want to intercept **everything** - not only the simple GET requests that represent page loads. I want to be able to see all requests, regardless of the verb, for example a POST request triggered by a HTML form. I want to see redirects.

What are the use cases:

- Attach additional headers to requests
- Read headers from responses
- Certificate pinning for every single request

I've read everything that I could find online. My conclusion is that there's no custom WebView implementation that I can plug into my application and satisfy my needs. The closest I've gotten so far is by using WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest. I execute the request by myself in a customized HTTP client (OkHttpClient) and return the response to the WebView.

Some key reasons why this doesn't work: Can't handle requests, executed within the HTML consistently; Even if I manage to handle them I can't get a hold onto the request body when it's a POST; I can't handle redirects. Last point is expanded in [another question by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636535/why-doesnt-webviewclient-shouldinterceptrequest-support-redirects-after-4-4).

[I read that shouldInterceptRequest was never intended for full network communication interception](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/android-webview-dev/FzajQrxaG48/rYl4pjQHEAAJ). 
Currently I'm asking if I can plug my HTTP client somewhere else so that I don't disturb the functionality of the WebView.

Here's my code:

WebViewClient:

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, String url) {
    Log.d(Constants.Tags.WEBVIEW_CLIENT, "WV REQUEST (OLD) " + url);
    return processRequest(url);
}

@Override
@TargetApi(21)
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, WebResourceRequest
        interceptedRequest) {
    Log.d(Constants.Tags.WEBVIEW_CLIENT, "WV REQUEST (NEW) " + interceptedRequest.getUrl
            ().toString() + " " + interceptedRequest.getMethod());
    return processRequest(interceptedRequest);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private WebResourceResponse processRequest(WebResourceRequest ir) {
    if (!"GET".equals(ir.getMethod())) {
        Log.d(Constants.Tags.WEBVIEW_CLIENT, "IGNORING " + ir.getMethod() + " " + ir.getUrl());
        return null;
    }
    return processRequest(ir.getUrl().toString());
}

private WebResourceResponse processRequest(String url) {
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    try {
        return processResponse(okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute());
    } catch (SSLHandshakeException e) {
        Log.d(Constants.Tags.WEBVIEW_CLIENT, "SSLHandshakeException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(Constants.Tags.WEBVIEW_CLIENT, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private WebResourceResponse processResponse(Response response) {
    String contentType = response.body().contentType().toString();

    if (contentType != null) {
        String mimeType = contentType;

        if (contentType.contains(";")) {
            mimeType = contentType.split(";")[0].trim();
        }

        WebResourceResponse webResourceResponse = new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, response
                .header("content-encoding", "utf-8")
                , response.body().byteStream());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) {
            webResourceResponse.setResponseHeaders(convertHeaders(response.headers()));
            webResourceResponse.setStatusCodeAndReasonPhrase(response.code(),"whatever");
        }

        return webResourceResponse;
    }
    return null;
}

private Map<String, String> convertHeaders(Headers headers) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
        map.put(headers.name(i), headers.value(i));
    }
    return map;
}
```

OkHttpClient:

```
public static OkHttpClient getNewHttpClient() {

    CertificatePinner.Builder certPinnerBuilder = new CertificatePinner.Builder();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : THUMB_PRINTS.entrySet()) {
        certPinnerBuilder.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    CertificatePinner certPinner = certPinnerBuilder.build();

    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .certificatePinner(certPinner)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new AdditionalHeaderInterceptor())
            .followRedirects(false)
            .followSslRedirects(false)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .connectTimeout(Constants.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(Constants.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(Constants.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .cache(null);

    return enableTls12OnPreLollipop(client).build();
}

public static OkHttpClient.Builder enableTls12OnPreLollipop(OkHttpClient.Builder client) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) {
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            sc.init(null, null, null);
            client.sslSocketFactory(new Tls12SocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory()));

            ConnectionSpec cs = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                    .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                    .build();

            List<ConnectionSpec> specs = new ArrayList<>();
            specs.add(cs);
            specs.add(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS);
            specs.add(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT);

            client.connectionSpecs(specs);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Log.e(Constants.Tags.GENERAL, "Error while setting TLS 1.2", exc);
        }
    }

    return client;
}
```

Comment: Why do you post the question 2 times? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636535/why-doesnt-webviewclient-shouldinterceptrequest-support-redirects-after-4-4

Comment: @Steven: This question is trying to solve my practical problem: intercept all WebView communication, while the other question concentrates on handling redirects within the WebView. Same code snippet, different focus.